# Laçamento de exceção

Tags: php

Considerando que a tabela "usuarios" não existe,gostaria de entender porque ao invés do `catch` ser executado, a função "errors" é executada

Codigo :

```
<?php

$usuario = 'root';

$senha ='';

function errors($e)
{
    echo "Erro dados";
}

set_exception_handler('errors');

try
{

    $conn1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste',$usuario, $senha);

}

catch(Exception $e){

    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o banco';

    die();  
}

try
{

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

    $resul = $conn1->query($sql);

    $resul = $resul->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($resul as $key => $value) {
        echo $key .": ". $value. "</br>";   
    }
}catch(Exception $e)
{

echo "Erro ao selecionar dados";

    die();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente não esta sendo lançada uma exception. Quando a sua query é executada, ela não retorna uma ResultSet, o que impossibilita a chamada da função fetch. Com isso o PHP lança um tipo de erro chamado E_NOTICE, o que não é uma instancia da classe Exception.

Enfim a única maneira (mais ou menos) de fazer o catch executar é lançar uma exception manualmente dentro do try. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
throw new Exception("Erro na consulta sql");
```

Exemplo para que o segundo try/catch funcione:

```
try
{
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    $resul = $conn1->query($sql);

    //quando a query sql falhar, por qualquer motivo, 
    //será retornado o boolean false.
    if($resul === false){
        throw new Exception("Erro na consulta sql, algum campo não existe");    
    }
    $resul = $resul->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($resul as $key => $value) {
    echo $key .": ". $value. "</br>";   
    }
}catch(Exception $e)
{

    echo "Erro ao selecionar dados: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();

}
```

Nesse caso o seu set_exception_handler não será mais executado nessa situação especifica.

Comment: Mas se uma exceção não é lançada, por quê a função definida em `set_exception_handler` é chamada?

Comment: Por que acontece um erro na execução do script (a chamada de uma função que não existe), embora esse erro não seja interpretado como uma instancia da classe Exception. Realmente aconteceu uma exceção na execução do codigo, mas não é o tipo que o laço try/catch espera.

Comment: Mas erros não são tratados por `set_exception_handler` e sim por `set_error_handler`. Eu testei o código da pergunta aqui e a exceção foi capturada como esperado. Se o banco de dados `teste` não existe, o construtor do PDO lançará uma exceção. Tem como explicar melhor a parte em que você afirma que não é lançada?

Comment: Na resposta eu me referia ao segundo try/catch (que era a duvida da pergunta, quando a tabela usuarios não existisse). O primeiro try/catch realmente executa o catch (pois a classe pdo faz um throw de uma exception do tipo PDOException, que em algum momento estende a classe Exception). No segundo try/catch, quando a query falha, a variavel $resul vai receber o valor false, depois quando se tenta acessar a função fetch a partir da variavel $resul, acontece um erro (que não deixa de ser uma exception em relação ao que deveria acontecer). Para o catch não aconteceu nada.

Comment: Nossa, eu podia jurar que o problema era no primeiro. Eu havia lido que o banco de dados não existia. Agora tudo faz sentido. Nesse caso acho que o melhor seria mesmo utilizar um `if` verificando o retorno da *query*. Talvez você possa adicionar a sua resposta.